# How do I keep iPad screen in landscape mode

Tags: ipad

I have a app that i want to run on iPhone and iPad.But I want iPad screens in landscape mode.
For that i write following code in ViewController.m file and set the orientation in landscape mode in .plist file. But it still show screen in portrait mode.

So please help me to design screen in landscape mode.

Thank you.

```
// iOS6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

// iOS6
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return (UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionLeftToRight || UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft);
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

    }

}

// Added after comment
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  following in your .m file

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
return toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

}